# C++ [Error] declaration of 'char ' shadows a parameter. what does it mean?

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I am trying to giving some `char` to a variable within a function by using `strcpy`. And I am getting the following errors

```
[Error] declaration of 'char str3 [100]' shadows a parameter
[Error] invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::string& {aka std::basic_string<char>&}' from an rvalue of type 'char*'
[Note] in passing argument 2 of 'void read_string(std::string&, std::string&)'
```

Here is my code as follows :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

void read_string(std::string &to, std :: string &str3)
{
    to = "test";
    std::cout << &to << std::endl;
    char str3[100];

    strcpy (str3,"copy successful");
    std::cout << str3<<std :: endl;


}

  int main()
  {
    std::string s = "This should be changed.";
    char ss[100];
    read_string(s,ss);
    std::cout << &s << std::endl;
    std::cout<<ss<<std::endl;
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: You should choose a different name for `str3`.

Comment: When you declare `str3` as a `char[]`, you’re ‘shadowing’ the parameter `str3` (a `std::string&`); `str3` now refers to something else, and the parameter can’t be accessed.

Comment: This is possibly the most confusing code I’ve ever read. I really can’t make out what it’s supposed to do.

Comment: Note that (aside from the missing `#include <string>` to provide the definition of `std::string`) the code in `read_string` is legal and its meaning is well defined. Any compiler that refuses to compile it does not conform to the language definition. This sometimes happens when code is compiled with a non-conforming option like "pretend that every warning that the compiler writer thought might be helpful is, in fact, an error".

Answer (score 4):

Your function parameter `std::string &str3` has the same name as `char str3[100];` inside your function body, you need to change one of your variables name.